# get new location of cv::rect after rotation image by warpAffine (opencv , c++)

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I want to get new location of a cv::rect (ROI) after rotate the image by using the following code :

```
cv::Point2f center(image.cols/2.0, image.rows/2.0);

cv::Rect ROI = cv::Rect(100,200,50,100);

cv::Mat rot = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
cv::Rect bbox = cv::RotatedRect(center,image.size(), angle).boundingRect();

rot.at<double>(0,2) += bbox.width/2.0 - center.x;
rot.at<double>(1,2) += bbox.height/2.0 - center.y;


cv::warpAffine(image, image, rot, bbox.size(),cv::INTER_LINEAR,cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,
               cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));
```

how I can do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have the rotation matrix, you can rotate the ROI rectangle using `cv::transform` function. First of all, you would need an array of points of that rectangle.

```
vector<Point2f> roi_points = {
        {roi.x,             roi.y},
        {roi.x + roi.width, roi.y},
        {roi.x + roi.width, roi.y + roi.height},
        {roi.x,             roi.y + roi.height}
};
```

Then, you can use `cv::transform`:

```
vector<Point2f> rot_roi_points;
transform(roi_points, rot_roi_points, rot);
```

This way, `rot_roi_points` holds points of the transformed rectangle.

[image]
**==>**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In order to get new location of a cv::rect (ROI) you have to transform each of its corners with using of following function:

```
cv::Point2f Convert(const cv::Point2f & p, const cv::Mat & t)
{
    float x = p.x*t.at<double>((0, 0) + p.y*t.at<double>((0, 1) + t.at<double>((0, 2); 
    float y = p.x*t.at<double>((1, 0) + p.y*t.at<double>((1, 1) + t.at<double>((1, 2); 
    return cv::Point2f(x, y);
}
```

The transformation matrix is the same as you used for image rotation.

Comment: thanks I changed your function as following :
cv::Point2f Convert(const cv::Point2f & p, const cv::Mat & t)
{
    float x = p.x*t.at<float>(0, 0) + p.y*t.at<float>(0, 1) + t.at<float>(0, 2);
    float y = p.x*t.at<float>(1, 0) + p.y*t.at<float>(1, 1) + t.at<float>(1, 2);
    return cv::Point2f(x, y);
}
and call the function as following :
cv::Point2f c1 = Convert(cv::Point2f(ROI.x,ROI.y),rot) ;
but I get very large float value (exp: -3.99357e+15). what is wrong ?

Comment: Because conversion matrix has double type.